# Python does not start with Gitbash (windows) even after adding it to .bashrc

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, git-bash

As shown in the picture below, I tried to configure Git Bash so I can use python directly in a new window by typing "python". 
For some reason it did not work in the new window. When I type "python", python does not run, and it allows me enter whatever I want , except spaces. I ran cat .bashrc in the new window and I get:

```
$ cat .bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:[/c/Users/rsb-7/.anaconda]:[/c/Users/rsb-7/.anaconda]/Scripts"
alias python="winpty python.exe"
export PATH="$PATH:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]/Scripts"
export PATH="$PATH:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]/Scripts"
alias python="winpty python.exe"
export PATH="$PATH:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]/Scripts"
alias python="winpty python.exe"
export PATH="$PATH:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]:[/c/Users/rsb-7/anaconda]/Scripts"
alias python="winpty python.exe"
```

Any thoughts?

[Configuration window on the left, new window on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utux2.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: _Any thoughts?_ Messing with the PATH like this sounds kind of risky. I would recommend removing all traces of what you added.